# Are there any links to data on Offense vs Defense win/loss ratio for various maps?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I am curious to see which maps in Team Fortress 2 favor Offense or Defense.  I know that Steam collects massive amounts of data on player statistics so they probably have the data somewhere.

Does anyone have a link to statistics on which maps have had more offense wins vs defense wins or vice versa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Valve used to show some statistic of Team Fortress 2 map at [this page](http://store.steampowered.com/stats/). But unfortunately they have recently removed maps statistic in favor of leaderboards and achievements only.

Another good source of TF2 data stats is [TF2Stats.net](http://tf2stats.net/maps/), but at the moment it shows only the popular maps and map saturation history. Could be that in future they will add more info.

**UPDATE:** I found a link to official `Valve's Team Fortress 2 Stats` via Google: [here](http://steampowered.com/status/tf2/tf2_stats.php). It doesn't contain custom maps stats, but only official maps.

[image]